# MySQL Update Table from Another Table Recursively

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, table1 and table2, where table1 is updated to fill in missing (null) values based on matching fields in table2 to create a more complete table1.

I have tried numerous queries such as

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2...SET...
```

and

```
UPDATE table1 SET ... (SELECT)...
```

However my results are always incomplete.  Note that I have a much larger dataset in both tables in terms of both columns and rows).  I just used this as simpler example.

Rules:

```
1) The `keyword` from table2 looks for a match in `keyword` in table1 and must accept partial matches.
2) No values can be overwritten in table1 (update null values only)
3) The lookup order is per run_order in table2.
```

Specific example:

Table1:

```
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|                  
|t1_id|keyword                        |category  |month|age      |skill  |
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|  
|  1  |childrens-crafts-christmas     |kids      |     |         |       |  
|  2  |kids-costumes                  |          |     |tween    |       |  
|  3  |diy-color-printable            |printable |     |         |easy   |  
|  4  |toddler-halloween-costume-page |          |     |         |       |  
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|
```

Table2:

```
|-----|---------|---------|----------|-----|----------|-------|
|t2_id|run_order|keyword  |category  |month|age       |skill  |
|-----|---------|---------|----------|-----|----------|-------|
|  1  |   1     |children |          |     |4-11 yrs  |       |
|  2  |   2     |printable|          |     |          |easy   |
|  3  |   3     |costume  |halloween | 10  |0-12 years|       |
|  4  |   4     |toddler  |          |     |1-3 years |       |
|  5  |   5     |halloween|holiday   | 10  |          |       |
|-----|---------|---------|----------|-----|----------|-------|
```

Result:

```
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|                  
|t1_id|keyword                        |category  |month|age      |skill  |
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|  
|  1  |childrens-crafts-christmas     |kids      |     |4-11 yrs |       |  
|  2  |kids-costumes                  |halloween | 10  |tween    |       |  
|  3  |diy-color-printable  printable |printable |     |         |easy   |  
|  4  |toddler-halloween-costume-page |holiday   | 10  |1-3 years|       |  
|-----|-------------------------------|----------|-----|---------|-------|
```

MySQL for schema and table data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2; 

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `t1_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `category` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `month` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `age` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `skill` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`));

  CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `t2_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run_order` INT NULL,
  `keyword` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `category` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `month` INT NULL,
  `age` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `skill` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t2_id`));

INSERT INTO `table1` (`keyword`, `category`) VALUES ('childrens-crafts-christmas', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`keyword`, `age`) VALUES ('kids-costumes', 'tween');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`keyword`, `category`, `skill`) VALUES ('diy-color-printable', 'printable', 'easy');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`keyword`) VALUES ('toddler-halloween-costume-page');

INSERT INTO `table2` (`run_order`, `keyword`, `age`) VALUES (1, 'children', '4-11 yrs');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`run_order`, `keyword`, `skill`) VALUES (2, 'printable', 'easy');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`run_order`, `keyword`, `category`, `month`, `age`) VALUES (3, 'costume', 'halloween', 10, '0-12 years');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`run_order`, `keyword`, `age`) VALUES (4, 'toddler', '1-3 years');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`run_order`, `keyword`, `category`, `month`) VALUES (5, 'halloween', 'holiday', 10);
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB.  I believe this is equivalent to MySQL 5.7. I am currently using XAMPP.

Comment: Your expected result does not seem to match with your requirements and sample data. Eg row 3 has category `'printable'`, but there is no such category in `table2`. row 4 has category `'holiday'`, but it should have matched on `'costume'` first, which would give category `'halloween'`.

Comment: Based on your requirement to lookup according to the `run_order` in `table2` it seems the row with `t1_id` should match on `costume`, not `toddler` or `halloween`

Comment: GMB - good catch.  An error on my part.  I updated the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update empty values in `table1` with the value in the corresponding column of the first matching record in `table2`, `run_order` wise. A typical solution is to use a combination of correlated subqueries to find the matching records in `table2` and keep only the one with lowest `run_order`.

Here is a query that will update null categories with this logic:

```
update table1 t1
set category = (
    select category
    from table2 t2
    where t2.run_order = (
            select min(t22.run_order) 
            from table2 t22 
            where 
                t1.keyword like concat('%', t22.keyword, '%') 
                and t22.category is not null
        )
)
where t1.category is null
```

This assumes that `run_order` is unique in `table2` (which seems relevant in your use case).

You can extend the logic for more columns with `coalesce()`. Here is the solution for columns `category` and `month`:

```
update table1 t1
set 
    category = coalesce(
        t1.category, 
        (
            select category
            from table2 t2
            where t2.run_order = (
                    select min(t22.run_order) 
                    from table2 t22 
                    where 
                        t1.keyword like concat('%', t22.keyword, '%') 
                        and t22.category is not null
                )
        )
    ),
    month = coalesce(
        t1.month, 
        (
            select month
            from table2 t2
            where t2.run_order = (
                    select min(t22.run_order) 
                    from table2 t22 
                    where 
                        t1.keyword like concat('%', t22.keyword, '%') 
                        and t22.month is not null
                )
        )
    )
where t1.category is null or t1.month is null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5320c38983adf958d81e1f117bcc5f3b)**

Comment: GMB, thanks for helping with the solution.  This works for the sample tables, but when I implement it for my larger tables, I get an error: subquery returns more than 1 row.  So I added LIMIT 1 after the first SELECT query.  I don't get errors but my table is not being updated as fully as it should (similar to previous queries I've tried). Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: @Crimony: is `run_order` a unique column in `table2`, or it contains duplicates?

Comment: it contains duplicates. If it is a problem, I could updated it to unique values.

Comment: @Crimony: yes you need unique values (I mentioned that in my answer already), otherwise we cannot reliably choose the relevant record to pick the missing values from.

Comment: @ GMB, yes you did mention it.  It apparently didn't register with me.  I will update them to unique values and rerun the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join between the 2 tables using a like expression and the if nul() function to ensure you don't overwrite non null values.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.keyword like concat("%",t2.keyword,"%")
SET 
    t1.category = ifnull(t1.category,t2.category),
    t1.age = ifnull(t1.age,t2.age),
    t1.skill = ifnull(t1.skill,t2.skill);
```